# Do I need external capacitors for this SMD Crystal?

Tags: crystal

I have [TXC 7B 16Mhz Crystal](https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/txc-corporation/7B-16.000MAAJ-T/887-1104-1-ND/2118981) and I am not sure if I need 18pF capacitors between GND pins and GND.

Comment: That depends as much on your oscillator as on your crystal.

Comment: It says 18pF (or specify) according to the datasheet http://www.txccrystal.com/images/pdf/7b.pdf

Comment: Again, it depends as much on the oscillator as on the crystal.  What you have is a crystal, some active oscillator circuit will make it oscillate.  Most of those need external capacitors to reach common crystal load capacitances, but some have enough on-chip.

Comment: Ok, reading the datasheet, I actually can't tell if the on-chip capacitance is 18pF or it requires 18pF externally. Which one is it?

Comment: The load capacitance value of 18 pF means you have to put an 18 pF capacitor (or something equivalent) in parallel with the crystal. In Niranjan's answer there are 2 capacitors, one on either side. They're not directly in parallel with the crystal but in series. So they need to be 36 pF each so that the total as seen from the crystal is 18 pF.

Comment: *if I need 18pF capacitors between GND pins and GND* You don't, the two GND pins must be connected to GND. They are only connected to the metal case of the crystal. The crystal itself is between the other 2 pins. You need the 18 pF between these 2 pins !

Comment: @b1gtuna you are looking at the wrong data sheet.  You must look at the data sheet of the oscillator you connect the crystal to, not just the data sheet of the crystal.  **Until you specify what oscillator the crystal is to be connected to, this question is unanswerable**.

Comment: @ChrisStratton ah I see what you mean. I am connecting it to Atmega32u4's xtal1/2 pins. Those are oscillator pins right?

Comment: @FakeMoustache Do you mean I need a capacitor between pin 3 and pin 1 as per the datasheet? http://www.txccrystal.com/images/pdf/7b.pdf

Comment: You should stop asking for confirmation on everything and assume that what is written by others is true until proven untrue. Look in the Atmega's datasheet how to connect a crystal or google "Atmega crystal circuit" and look at the images (not the websites). Notice how all circuits are the same. So build that. Notice how there is a cap on each side of the crystal connections. Then remember what I wrote about 18 pf and 36 pF.

Comment: @FakeMoustache haha thanks. I didn't think to check the MCU's datasheet. Will do!

Answer (score -4):

Most of the time crystal oscillator with capacitor combination is used for sample and hold purpose, time required to generate sufficient amount of oscillations for  purpose defines your your capacitance values. If lookout in datasheets then you will get it!  You can see this also
[image]

Comment: The text/picture you pasted here is relevant. Your own text is nonsense. *used for sample and hold purpose* Geez ! Not true at all.

Comment: Of interest to me is where you found the picture in your answer.

Comment: @Andyaka http://www.eetasia.com/ARTICLES/2001SEP/2001SEP06_AMD_AN.PDF?SOURCES=DOWNLOAD looks like a legit original source. At least it has proper attribution in the PDF.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - good find but I'm interested in the marked up picture with the red and blue boxes around certain parts of text. It looks like something I might have done but I can't find it.